# How to complete the mini-game after beating the Giant Persian

Tags: god-of-war

I've just beaten the Giant Persian.

There's a mini game with two naked women. I press <kbd>O</kbd> to activate it. I have to tap the two buttons shown.

After that, there's an icon that represents a half circle like;

[image: half circle]

Ok, it's not like the real one but you got the idea :-)

According to [this walktrough](http://www.mahalo.com/god-of-war-chains-of-olympus-walkthrough/):

> Go up to the women and press O to activate a button-press minigame.
>   When the L+R shoulder buttons appear on the screen, you have to tap
>   them alternately and not simply hold them down. Successfully
>   completing the minigame grants you a large number of red orbs.

What I have to do after tapping the 2 buttons? I don't understand what I have to do when the half circle appears. It fills up and disappear then the mini game fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move the analog stick in the direction shown.  In this case, you'd want to move the left analog stick clockwise in order to clear this part of the minigame.

I always also started the circle wherever the line started (ie, in this case, I'd pull the stick downwards, and then move it in a circular motion clockwise towards the top) but I don't know if that's required, or just me overinterpreting the instructions. :)

If you're doing it right, the urn will shake and eventually fall off the nearby nightstand, I guess representing your "success" with the ladies.